# How to remove the outer tags(<tag></tag>) and append the rest to its parent using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here iam developing a chrome extenstion which selects one element and then we need to remove the outer tag and append the rest to same previous tag.

Suppose my html structure is like this..

```
<span>
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrolldelay="75" scrollamount="1" width="450" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 1, 0);" style="width: 450px;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000" width="450">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><b><u>Message</u></b>&nbsp;<img src="images/sir.jpg"></td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
</marquee>
</span>
```

All i have is selected span element and then selected marquee element.So i want to remove the marquee tag and append it back to span tag.

Final structure should look like this...

```
<span>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#000000" width="450">

<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><b><u>Message</u></b>&nbsp;<img src="images/sir.jpg"></td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
</span>
```

Code i have written :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");

    function getinfo() {
        message = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        message_length =message.length -1;
        message_body = message[message_length];
        console.log(message_body);

        var child = message_body.children[0];

        console.log(child);
        //Upto here i hace selected the marquee element
        //Now remove the <marquee> tag
        //Also remove the </marquee> tag
        //Append it back to the span tag

    }

    setTimeout(getinfo, 10000);

});
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but is there a specific reason for using a `<marquee>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('marquee table').unwrap()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**contents**](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the content of the `marquee` tag and then replace marquess with child dom

Since you have tagged this question

```
 function getinfo() {
       var childDom = $("marquee").contents();
      $("marquee").replaceWith(childDom);

    }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/20kg64nm/1/)

You can also use [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove the parent element

```
function getinfo() {
    var getChild = $('table');
       getChild.unwrap()
   }
```

[**JSFIDDLE with unwrap method**](https://jsfiddle.net/20kg64nm/2/)

Note: Since you have tagged it with jquery so usng jquery, though I dont see jquery in your code